# created a PDF that outputs weird characters

Tags: pdf-generation

This is my code which will get data from the database then store it in a table for .pdf file:

```
<?php

// test the table functions
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('includes/pdf/class.ezpdf.php');
  //echo 'AAA-1-';
  $pdf = new Cezpdf();
  //$pdf->selectFont('./fonts/Helvetica');

  //connect to db
  session_start();
  require_once('connect/ticketivity_connect.php');
  //echo 'AAA-2-';


  //get customer details
  $sql_cust = "SELECT * FROM customers where customer_id = '".$_GET['customerid']."'";
  $res_cust = mysql_query($sql_cust);
  $num_cust = mysql_num_rows($res_cust);
  $row_cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_cust);

  //display customer details
  $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Customer Name:', 'second' => $row_cust['cust_name']);
  $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Phone Number:', 'second' => $row_cust['cust_phone']);
  $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Address:', 'second' => $row_cust['cust_address']);
  $db_data[] = array('first' => '>Customer Ref/ Room Number:', 'second' => $row_cust['cust_ref']);
  //echo 'AAA-3-';
  //get order
  $sql_orderinfo= "SELECT * FROM orders where customer_id = '".$_GET['customerid']."'";
  $res_orderinfo = mysql_query($sql_orderinfo);
  $num_orderid = mysql_num_rows($res_orderinfo);
  $row_orderid = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_orderinfo); 
  //echo 'AAA-4-';
  //display order id
  $orderid_len = strlen($row_orderid['order_id']);
  if($orderid_len == 1) { 
   //echo 'AAA1--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => '00000'.$row_orderid['order_id']);
  } else if ($orderid_len == 2){ 
   //echo 'AAA2--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => '0000'.$row_orderid['order_id']);
  } else if ($orderid_len == 3){ 
   //echo 'AAA3--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => '000'.$row_orderid['order_id']);
  } else if ($orderid_len == 4){
   //echo 'AAA4--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => '00'.$row_orderid['order_id']);
  } else if ($orderid_len == 5){ 
   //echo 'AAA5--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => '0'.$row_orderid['order_id']);
  } else if ($orderid_len == 6){
   //echo 'AAA6--';
   $db_data[] = array('first' => 'Order ID:', 'second' => $row_orderid['order_id']);
  } 

  //table columns
  $col_names = array(
   'first' => 'first',
   'second' => 'second',
  );
  //echo 'AAA-5-';
  $table_title = 'Customer Details';
  //echo 'AAA-6-';
  $pdf->ezTable($db_data, $col_names, $table_title, array('width'=>550));
  if (isset($d) && $d){
   //echo 'AAA-if';
   $pdfcode = $pdf->output(1);
   $pdfcode = str_replace("\n","\n<br>", $pdfcode);
   echo '<html><body>';
   echo trim($pdfcode);
   echo '</body></html>';
  } else {
   //echo 'AAA-else';
   $pdf->ezStream();
  }

?>
```

Output:

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (R and OS php pdf writer, http://www.ros.co.nz) /CreationDate (D:20100817) >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents [ 7 0 R 8 0 R ] >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 120 >> stream x��2�300P@&�ҹ�,�\����`di�gfb�`ah�gai�����`h�d�)(h8����)���$f�k*�d)��pb1h����8sK�qF�@����F@��m\����-� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 94 >> stream x��2�300P@&�ܹʹ�,���L,��,, r`"�@$��Qi����Jct�03�|C4��(" �7����2D�a����T4z endstream endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000015 00000 n 0000000080 00000 n 0000000126 00000 n 0000000257 00000 n 0000000286 00000 n 0000000391 00000 n 0000000464 00000 n 0000000657 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 823 %%EOF
```

What do I need to do/add?

Comment: By the way, I'm using http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/ as reference. I downloaded the zip file: pdfClassesAndFonts_009e.

Comment: You need to view the output in a PDF viewer, by the look of it, that's the actual contents of the PDF file.

Comment: It’d be helpful if you could reformat this question so that the code is legible.

Comment: Is this valid: 

$db_data = array( 
array('first'=> 'Customer Name:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_name']) ,array('first'=> 'Phone Number:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_phone']) ,array('first'=> 'Address:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_address']) ,array('first'=> 'Customer Ref/ Room Number:','second'=>$row_cust['cust_ref']) );

Answer (score 1):

The question isn’t very clear, but I assume you’re writing a web application, and you’re trying to serve up the PDF document to the client.

First, you need to set a header to let the client know that it should expect PDF data:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

That will cause most browsers to render the PDF within the browser window. If you’d rather have the browser offer the PDF as a download, do this in addition to the above:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
```

You may set any filename you like in place of `filename.pdf`.

It’s important that you make these calls to `header()` before *any* output is written.

As an aside, I guess that `$d` is a debug flag, but I don’t think it’s a very good idea to do those string operations that you’re doing when it’s set. You’re likely to end up corrupting the PDF data.

Comment: Thank you! Is this valid?

$db_data = array(
    array('first'=> 'Customer Name:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_name'])
    ,array('first'=> 'Phone Number:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_phone'])
    ,array('first'=> 'Address:','second'=> $row_cust['cust_address'])
    ,array('first'=> 'Customer Ref/ Room Number:','second'=>$row_cust['cust_ref'])
    ); 

where Ex .($row_cust['cust_ref']) is data from the DB.

Comment: I added the header as u said,but i am still getting the pdf -3 0 0 error

Comment: could u solve the issue ? im getting same result on mobile chrome . Thanks

Comment: If the answer above doesn’t help you, you’re either doing something else wrong or you aren’t reading the answer correctly. I can’t read your mind and figure out which.